# Change order of expansions(bash)

Tags: linux, bash, expansion

I need parameter expansion after command substitution.

GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)

```
$ foo() { echo \$a; }
$ a=5
$ echo $(foo)
$a
```

Is it possible?

test:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $a
```

run:

```
a=5
echo $(./test)
```

if test:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo \$a
```

run:

```
echo $(./test)
$a
```

Don't work(

Comment: Didn't get your question? Can you clarify? You want that the result of echo is the contents of a? Remove the backslash!

Comment: @rems I update question

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Order can't be changed without changing source code.

You can use eval:

```
eval echo $(foo)
```

man bash:

```
   The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde  expansion,  parame‐
   ter,  variable  and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done
   in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.
```

Answer (score 2):

... What?

```
$ foo() { echo $a; }
$ a=42
$ echo $(foo)
42
```

Comment: @Ignacio Don't work, I update question

Comment: Of course your first test doesn't work. You forgot to export the variable.

Comment: @Ignacio how can I do?

Comment: With `export a=5`.

Comment: @Ignacio It work only if inner command expand variable. python don't expand output. I also need use eval.

Comment: Then your question is fallacious, since that has nothing to do with order of expansion.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo `eval foo`
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: echo `eval $(./test)` 5: command not found

Comment: Should be "echo $(eval foo)" or as I wrote "echo \`eval foo\`".

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
$ a=5
$ foo() { echo \$a; }
$ foo
$a
$ eval echo $(foo)
5
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $a
```

Run:

```
$ a=5
$ ./test
$ export a
$ ./test
5
```

New script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'echo $a'
```

Run:

```
$ a=5
$ ./test
echo $a
$ eval $(./test)
5
```

Python example:

```
$ a=5
$ python -c 'print "echo $a"'
echo $a
$ eval $(python -c 'print "echo $a"')
```

Another Python example:

```
$ a=5
$ python -c 'print "a=42"'
a=42
$ echo $a
5
$ declare $(python -c 'print "a=42"')
$ echo $a
42
```